# django.utils.crypto get_random_string() causing duplicate key error?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `get_random_string()` from `django.utils.crypto` to generate a random short_id for my model. There's only a few dozen entries.

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    short_id = models.CharField(default=get_random_string, max_length=12, unique=True)
```

For some reason, I'm getting a duplicate key error when I try to run my migration:

Any ideas?

```
DETAIL:  Key (short_id)=(88hUwNQjTIns) is duplicated.
```

Comment: Is `MyModel` already created or you are creating it now with short_id being a `random_string` and `Unique`?

Comment: @Jyothi S it’s an existing model with a field being added.

Comment: @aroooo So, the error just means.. your table as entries with `short_id` field having same values. This throws error. Why ? Because you are trying to set it as `unique` and there are entries which are denying the new rule.
So you can just revisit the table, remove unnecessary entries or empty the table before running migrations.